# Google CrUX data missing for the last few months?

Tags: chrome-ux-report

Google has CrUX data for my site between 2020-01 and 2020-10, but strangely none from 2020-11 onward.

For example, querying the BigQuery dataset for 2020-10 shows data:

```
> SELECT count(origin) FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.202010` where origin = 'https://sheertex.com'
1
```

But nothing appears in the datasets from 2020-11 and onward:

```
> SELECT count(origin) FROM `chrome-ux-report.all.202011` where origin = 'https://sheertex.com'
0
```

I'm not aware of any substantive changes to the site in November, and Google Analytics shows no material difference in traffic between October and November.

What could cause this?

Answer (score 1):

I do see origin-level data for this website in PageSpeed Insights, indicating that it should be available in BigQuery: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fsheertex.com&tab=mobile

[image: PSI results showing origin data]

However, I can confirm that 202010 is the most recent dataset in which it was included. The most recent dataset is 202103, which only covers the month of March, so it's possible that your site's popularity is increasing and it wasn't yet high enough to be included in the March dataset.

I'd suggest checking PSI again at the end of this month (April 2021) to confirm that you're still getting origin-level data. If so, I would definitely expect it to appear in BigQuery. Otherwise, that would indicate that your site's popularity is fluctuating below the [undisclosed] threshold for inclusion.